# Can't control fan on Fedora

Tags: fedora, hardware, fan

After upgrading to Fedora 27 (and now FC30) the fan on my old Dell workstation is running very fast.

I have tried using lm_sensors package and "fancontrol".

My system is as follows:

```
> sensors
coretemp-isa-0001
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +35.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +103.0°C)
Core 1:       +35.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +103.0°C)
Core 2:       +36.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +103.0°C)
Core 3:       +34.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +103.0°C)

dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
Processor Fan:    794 RPM
Processor Fan:   1102 RPM
Motherboard Fan: 1132 RPM
Ambient:          +17.0°C

nouveau-pci-0300
Adapter: PCI adapter
GPU core:     +1.18 V  (min =  +1.05 V, max =  +1.18 V)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +37.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +103.0°C)
Core 1:       +40.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +103.0°C)
Core 2:       +40.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +103.0°C)
Core 3:       +40.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +103.0°C)

nouveau-pci-0400
Adapter: PCI adapter
GPU core:     +1.05 V  (min =  +0.75 V, max =  +1.10 V)
temp1:        +43.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
```

Output from pwmconfig

```
> pwmconfig

# Initial output from
hwmon0 is nouveau
   hwmon1 is nouveau
   hwmon2 is dell_smm
   hwmon3 is coretemp
   hwmon4 is coretemp

Found the following PWM controls:
   hwmon2/pwm1           current value: 255
   hwmon2/pwm2           current value: 255
   hwmon2/pwm3           current value: 255

Giving the fans some time to reach full speed...
Found the following fan sensors:
   hwmon2/fan1_input     current speed: 947 RPM
   hwmon2/fan2_input     current speed: 1530 RPM
   hwmon2/fan3_input     current speed: 1230 RPM
```

I tried to manually write the /etc/fancontrol file:

```
INTERVAL=5
DEVPATH=hwmon0=devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:03:00.0 hwmon1=devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:04:00.0 hwmon2=devices/virtual/hwmon/hwmon2/device hwmon3=devices/platform/coretemp.0 hwmon4=devices/platform/coretemp.1
DEVNAME=hwmon0=nouveau hwmon1=nouveau hwmon2=dell_smm hwmon3=coretemp hwmon4=coretemp
FCTEMPS=hwmon2/device/pwm1=hwmon2/temp1_input hwmon2/device/pwm2=hwmon2/temp2_input hwmon2/device/pwm3=hwmon2/temp3_input
FCFANS=hwmon2/device/pwm1=hwmon2/fan1_input hwmon2/device/pwm2=hwmon2/fan2_input hwmon2/device/pwm3=hwmon2/fan3_input
MINTEMP=hwmon2/device/pwm1=20
MAXTEMP=hwmon2/device/pwm1=55
MINSTART=hwmon2/device/pwm1=150
MINSTOP=hwmon2/device/pwm1=105
MINTEMP=hwmon2/device/pwm2=20
MAXTEMP=hwmon2/device/pwm2=55
MINSTART=hwmon2/device/pwm2=150
MINSTOP=hwmon2/device/pwm2=105
MINTEMP=hwmon2/device/pwm3=20
MAXTEMP=hwmon2/device/pwm3=55
MINSTART=hwmon2/device/pwm3=150
MINSTOP=hwmon2/device/pwm3=105
```

I got those values by searching for the devices and names:

```
# Devices
for d in `seq 0 5`
do
  readlink -f /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon$d/device | sed -e 's/^\/sys\///'
done

devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:03:00.0
devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:04:00.0
devices/virtual/hwmon/hwmon2/device
devices/platform/coretemp.0
devices/platform/coretemp.1

# Names:
for d in `seq 0 5`
do
  cat /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon$d/name
done

nouveau
nouveau
dell_smm
coretemp
coretemp
```

When I run fancontrol it says:

```
Device path of hwmon2 has changed
Configuration appears to be outdated, please run pwmconfig again
```

When I run pwmconfig I can hear it slow one of the fans, so it seems to be able to influence the hardware. After pwmconfig has written a config file, I run fancontrol but it issues errors:

1. it can't read from /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/pwm1
   and if I comment that line out (manually set the value so the script can continue)
2. it then can't write to the same file

If I manually write the revised value to that file, it seems to get overwritten almost immediately. Perhaps a hardware sensor writes to that file?

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?